# Axis generating nill on a non null element for intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, axis

I have the same problem with the question asked here;

[Axis generating nil on a non null Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837869/axis-generating-nil-on-a-non-null-array)

But i have to find a solution or workaround for this in intellij idea. Does anyone know if there is any preference or configuration for intellij idea like "Prefers building beans to straight arrays for wrapped XML array types" in eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to stop using Axis. Trust me on this. I migrated Axis 1.1 to 1.4 because the backend was upgraded, and then it was upgraded again, and strict validations were introduced, so I had to migrate to CXF. And soon I will do the same thing for other component, because new backend requires WSS...

Comment: unfortunately i don't have that luxury. I can't even migrate to axis 2 so i have to solve this by axis 1.4 or lower. Tried to generate by using axis 1.3 but still no progress